# Elastchsearch exception for large input text search using wildcardquery ,Eg"reason": "input automaton is too large: 1001""

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, wildcard-mapping

while performing wildcard search on elastic documents with large input text(more than 1000 characters)

I'm getting this exception  for "starts with" search

my starts with search eg: "myinputtext..*"
myinputtext = more than 1000 characters

detailed exception: Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/index_133/_search?pre_filter_shard_size=128&typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: input automaton is too large: 1001"}}}]},"status":400}

my request sample is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "indexId": {
              "value": 133,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "inputTextDetails.searchInput.input.keyword": {
                        "wildcard": "myinputtext sample*",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "inputTextDetails",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "none",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

and my mappings.json is:

```
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "with_keyword_custom_normalizer": {
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 4000,
              "normalizer": "lower_case_normalizer"
            }
          }
        },
        "path_match": "inputTextDetails.searchInput.*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please suggest me your thoughts on searching for large inputs on large data fields.
thanks for your help.